# Make every anchor tag with hash (#) in href unclickabe

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to achieve this in javascript. Below is the example of anchor tag

```
<a href="#">Example</a>
```

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `#` or also any href that starts with a hash, like `#top`?

Comment: @rafi Well, my current need was only of `#`. In other words, an empty tag which don't redirect to other page OR any certain section of current page. But if you have any solution for `#top` type href then you should post, it might help some future viewers of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property to `none`

```css
a[href="#"]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Example</a>
<br>
<a href="">Clickable Link Example</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

With event delegation, you can attach an event listener to the body and `preventDefault` when any `<a>` is clicked which has that href.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const a = e.target.closest('a');
  if (a.href === '#') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#">Example</a>
```

That'll prevent the `#` in the URL. If you want to make it truly unclickable, you can use `pointer-events: none`.

```css
a[href="#"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**For any hash href, like `#top`**

The solutions so far assume the href is exactly `#`. If you want to prevent clicks on any href starting with a hash, like `#top`, you could do that too.

The CSS approach, with a fancier [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
a[href^="#"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The JS approach:

```
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.closest('a[href^="#"]')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```